# How Can I Validate that an Email is from a Particular Domain in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building an application which will be initially rolled out to specific college campuses.

I would like to ensure that, when a user signs up, and provides their email address, that it is their school provided email to ensure that only legitimate students have access to the service.

Does anyone have any example or ideas on how to accomplish this? perhaps with a custom validation attribute?

**NOTE:**
More specifically, I just need to ensure that the email they enter is a .edu email address

Looks like regex is the way to go...can anyone provide some guidance on the proper expression?

Comment: Do you want to validate that the actual domain exists or just that it ends in .edu?

Comment: ending in .edu would most likely be sufficient. Another option, I suppose would be to store the domains in my db and check against that.

Comment: Is there a quick way to check for .edu using regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a Regular Expression Attribute and custom DataAnnotation. Register the annotation under Application_Start in your Global. Then you can use the validation as a DataAnnotation in your model both client and server side. I have a RegularExpressAttributes.cs class that contains all my commonly used regular expressions; all I do is drop it into my projects. If folks want it just let me know.

The View:

```
<div class="editor-field span-7">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
</div>
```

Regular Expression Attribute

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ProjectsMVC.Helpers
{
    #region RegularExpressionAttributes
    /// <summary>
    /// Email validation regular expression attribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Validates person@someplace.com, some.person@someplace.com, some_person@some+place.com and combinations thereof.</remarks>
    public class ValidateEmailAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        // public ValidateEmailAttribute()
        //     : base(@"^\S?([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$") { }

        public ValidateEmailAttribute()
            : base(@)@"^\S?([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@someplace.com$") {}
    }   

    #region DataAnnotationsModelValidator
    public class EmailValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<ValidateEmailAttribute>
    {
        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Error message
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string _errorMessage;

        /// <summary>
        /// Regular expression pattern
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string _pattern;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EmailValidator"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="metaData">The meta data.</param>
        /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
        /// <param name="attribute">The attribute.</param>
        public EmailValidator(ModelMetadata metaData, ControllerContext context, ValidateEmailAttribute attribute)
            : base(metaData, context, attribute)
        {
            this._errorMessage = attribute.ErrorMessage;
            this._pattern = attribute.Pattern;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves a collection of client validation rules.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A collection of client validation rules.</returns>
        public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRegexRule(this._errorMessage, this._pattern);
            return new[] { rule };
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Global.ascx.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    // Register custom model validators
    DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(ValidateEmailAttribute), typeof(EmailValidator));
}
```

Lastly the Model, User.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using ProjectsMVC.Helpers;

namespace ProjectsMVC.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(User_Validation))]
    public partial class User
    {
        public string ProperName
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName);
            }
        }

        public string DirectoryName
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0}, {1}", this.LastName, this.FirstName);
            }
        }

        public string IsUserActive
        {
            get
            {
                return Dictionaries.TrueOrFalse.First(t => t.Key == this.IsActive).Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public class User_Validation
    {
        [Display(Name = "eName")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
        [ValidateEname(ErrorMessage = "invalid")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First DirectoryName")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last DirectoryName")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
        [ValidateEmail(ErrorMessage = "invalid")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Active User")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a **custom validator** please refer to [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx), it has a very good explanation for MVC model validation.

You should use a **regular expression attibute** as the validator for the email field in the model. This is also explained in the article.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) and construct the appropriate regex to your particular domain.

Answer (score 1):

Custom validation Attribute did you say?  Here's a guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618485

Answer (score 1):

If the user belong to specific college need have specific email suffix.
You can store it in table and then when user logins to the system to check the suffix
according to the college.

If you need to check valid email address , you can use regular expression.

See example code C# to check valid email.

```
  Regex re = new Regex(@"\w.\w@{1,1}\w[.\w]?.\w");
            return re.IsMatch(email);
```

Comment: How can I modify this to validate that the email ends int ".edu"?

Answer (score 1):

There is `RemoteAttribute` validation attribute ([RemoteAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)).
In its parameters you can specify controller's action that can do validation process.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally we can have a school drop down, student need to select the school and enter the email address.

Then we can have a mapping of school name and email format.

```
school name - ABC
email format - [\w]+[\.\-\_]?[\w]+@ABC.[edu|org]
```

Email format can vary, based on provider.

These thing can be part of web.config

```
<Web.config>
<appsettings>
<add key="ABC" value="[\w]+[\.\-\_]?[\w]+@ABC.[edu|org]"/>
.
.
.
```

We can read value from config using ConfigurationManager.

Further, your model can inherit from IValidatableObject and override Validate method to validate email address, if not valid throw back a ValidationRessult, which can be displayed on view as Validation Error